# How to pass a delegate as an argument to subscribe as an event handler?

Tags: c#, events, delegates

I have an external application that provides an event `StkQuit`.

I subscribe to this event in a static class that handles all communication between my application and [the] external application. I would like to subscribe to the `StkQuit` event using another handler that sits on my form class.

This handler will inform the user that the external application has been closed. I would like to have a generic method in the static class called `SubscribeToStkQuit` that accepts a delegate as a parameter and subscribes that delegate (referring to the handler on my form class) to the `StkQuit` event.

Is this possible? Is this the most elegant/simplistic way to achieve such functionality?

My example code:

**Form Class**

```
public delegate void dForceClose();
public void SubscribeToStkQuit(dForceClose forceClose)
{
    UtilStk.SubscribeToStkQuit(forceClose = new dForceClose(ForceClose));
}
private void ForceClose()
{
    MessageBox.Show("TEST");
}
```

**Static Class**

```
private static AgUiApplication _stkUiApplication;
public static void SubscribeToStkQuit(Delegate subscribeHandler)
{
    _stkUiApplication.OnQuit += subscribeHandler;          
}
```

**[Update]**

As per comments I have updated the code like so:

```
public delegate void dForceClose(object sender, EventArgs e);
public void SubscribeToStkQuit(dForceClose forceClose)
{
    UtilStk.SubscribeToStkQuit(forceClose = new dForceClose(ForceClose));
}
private void ForceClose(object sender, Eventargs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("TEST");
}
```

I am still getting the cast exception. Any ideas ??

**[Update #2]**

I'm still having problems with this. In my static class I have a handler already for when `OnQuit` fires:

```
private static AgUiApplication _stkUiApplication;
public static bool CheckThatStkIsAvailable()
{
    object stkApplication = null;
    try
    {
        stkApplication = Marshal.GetActiveObject(_stkProgId);
        _stkUiApplication = stkApplication as AgUiApplication;
        _stkUiApplication.OnQuit += StkQuit;
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        // handle this
    }
}

private static void StkQuit()
{
    _stkUiApplication.OnQuit -= StkQuit;
    Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(_stkUiApplication);
    Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(_stkRoot);
}
```

This works fine. So I thought I would create a public property for _stkUiApplication and subscribe from the form class in the same manner:

**Static Class**

```
public static AgUiApplication StkUiApplication
{
    get { return _stkUiApplication; }
}
```

**Form Class**

```
private void SubscribeToStkQuit()
{
    UtilStk.StkUiApplication.OnQuit += StkQuit;
}

private void StkQuit()
{
    MessageBox("TEST");
}
```

Comment: That looks wonderfully elegant/simple to me...what part don't you like?

Comment: @Cpfohl - `_stkUiApplication.OnQuit += subscribeHandler;` throws "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Delegate' to 'AGI.Ui.Application.IAgUiApplicationEvents_OnQuitEventHandler'..." So I cast the delegate to the aforementioned type and I get a runtime exception "Unable to cast object of type dForceClose to type AGI.Ui.Application.IAgUiApplicationEvents_OnQuitEventHandler". Any ideas?

Comment: (Sorry! I didn't look carefully), but take a peek at @CrapHands' answer.  He caught the problem.  All .NET events must have the 'object sender, EventArgs e' signature.

Comment: Just to reiterate, i dont think you should be hooking up to the event like that, you will leak memory.
Best bet, is to hook up the event to another static event in Global.asax or some run once code somewhere.
Do this:
UtilStk.OnQuit += (sender, args) => SomeClassInMyApp.TheStaticMethodToHandleIt();

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you subscribe to a static event with an instance method, then the instance will not be garbage collected until the static event is disposed (unless you unsubscribe).

This will cause a memory leak.

Beyond that, the problem with your code is that the signature of `ForceClose()` does not match `_stkUiApplication.OnQuit` it needs to be `ForceClose(object sender, SomeKindOfEventArgs e)`

It should be `UtilStk.SubscribeToStkQuit(forceClose => (s, e){ForceClose();});`

EDIT:

The reference to your external app is static:

```
private static AgUiApplication _stkUiApplication;
```

so it will live for the duration of your application. Adding an event handler to

```
 _stkUiApplication.OnQuit
```

passes a reference to a method on the instance of your form class. This reference will now be held for the life of your application, so it cannot be garbage collected.

To handle for this situation, either explicitly de-register (-=) the handler when the listening object is disposed, or handle static events with static handlers.

I mistakenly thought that you were describing web forms at first, which changes things a bit (you may only ever instantiate one `Form`), but the above holds true regardless. And it is good practice.

To solve your current problem:
You need to type the parameter passed to:

```
public static void SubscribeToStkQuit(Delegate subscribeHandler)
{
    _stkUiApplication.OnQuit += subscribeHandler;          
}
```

to be the type of `_stkUiApplication.OnQuit`

Something like

```
public static void SubscribeToStkQuit(EventHandler<EventArgs> subscribeHandler)
{
    _stkUiApplication.OnQuit += subscribeHandler;          
}
```

Then you can do this:

```
public void SubscribeToStkQuit()
{
    UtilStk.SubscribeToStkQuit((sender, args) => ForceClose(sender, args));
}
```

Comment: Is it suitable to unsubscribe `-=` in the instance method itself?

Comment: Also, the `OnQuit` event, namely, `event IAgUiApplicationEvents_OnQuitEventHandler OnQuit;` is not static. The static method `SubscribeToStkQuit` is used to assign the handler which is an instance method. Can you explain the memory leak a little more so I can understand :D?

Comment: For some reason the lambda expression gives me problems when passing "object sender, Eventargs args" into ForceClose. My line is like so: `UtilStk.SubscribeToStkQuit((sender, e) => ForceClose(object sender, EventArgs e));` - I cant seem to see any difference between mine and yours?

Comment: @WulfgarPro Should have been more explicit. When I said something like, i meant that you need to find the actual type of the event args. hover over _stkUiApplication.OnQuit in VS to find out its actual type, and replace the one here with that. also, 
UtilStk.SubscribeToStkQuit((sender, args) => ForceClose(object sender, Eventargs args));
should be
UtilStk.SubscribeToStkQuit((sender, args) => ForceClose(sender, args));

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can!

But it's better to use actions and functions, which are flexible in terms of parametrization (all of them are in System namespace).

Anyway, I've another suggestion: why don't you use event accessors? You can create one in your static class:

```
public event EventHandler Quit { add { _stkUiApplication.OnQuit += value; } remove { _stkUiApplication.OnQuit -= value; } }
```

About actions and functions, these are delegates too, so you can use them everywhere as input parameters for any delegation.

Perhaps you can use the event accessor and do it in a .NET way, can't you?